# Is remote measurement of isotope ratios possible, or must a sample be aquired

Tags: telescope, observational-astronomy, light, spectroscopy

Is it possible to measure to measure isotopic abundance of remote astronomical objects - ie measurement without having a sample to feed into a mass spectrometer? Do different isotopes show any differences in absorption or emission spectra which can be used for this purpose?

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and say no to this.  When doing distance spectroscopy, what you're really looking at is emission and absorption of photons from electrons.  The number and orbital arrangement of electrons should rely almost entirely on the number of protons.  So the number of neutrons won't affect the emission or absorption spectra in any measurable way, especially at astronomical distances.  Of course, I could be wrong about how much of an effect the neutrons have on the electrons, which is why this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, isotopic ratios can be readily established by spectroscopy.

Molecules where the constituent atoms differ by one mass unit have different vibrational and rotational energy levels and the gaps between them depend on the [reduced mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_mass) of the molecule.

For example, in a diatomic molecule
$$ \mu = \frac{m_1 m_2}{m_1 + m_2}$$
and the vibrational frequencies depend on $\mu^{-1/2}$.

This technique is used for example to look at carbon monoxide feature in the infrared and establish the ratio of $^{13}$C/$^{12}$C.

The [isotopic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopic_shift) for atoms is much smaller in general, but is still detectable. The different mass of the nucleus changes the reduced mass of the electron (a little) and this changes the wavelength of the characteristic transition.

An interesting example of this has been the search for $^6$Li in the spectra of population II stars (e.g. [Asplund et al. 2006](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0510636)). This isotope of Li should be produced in the big bang along with the more common $^7$Li but is more readily burned in stellar interiors.

The main optical resonance line of lithium occurs at 670.8 nm. The difference between the  wavelength of this line (actually, it is an unresolved doublet) is 0.015nm. This separation cannot be resolved in stellar spectra and instead the shape of the absorption line has to be modelled to estimate the $^6$Li/$^7$Li ratio.

The isotopic shifts become *smaller* for heavier elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You say "The isotopic shifts become smaller for heavier elements" - Does this imply that above a certain atomic number the measurement becomes impractical?

Comment: @MikeH To be honest I am not familiar with any atomic spectroscopy in astrophysics that looks at isotopic ratios in anything heavier than Li.

Comment: So I understand from your answers that only three elements that can have their isotope ratios measured (H, He & Li) Are there no methods available for the rest of the periodic table?

Comment: @MikeH You understand wrong. I specifically give the example of carbon. Isotopic shifts in molecular spectroscopy are much larger.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. So is it the case that in stars, where no molecules exist, Li is the upper limit?

Comment: @MikeH I *think* that is true, but wouldn't be altogether surprised if somebody jumps in with a contradiction. Getting Li isotopic ratios in hot stars by atomic spectroscopy would be practically impossible too - the lines are too weak and too broad.